# how to set desired error threshold in keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to learn how to use keras and i'm wondering if i can set my own error threshold, but i'm confused. Can someone help me? suppose i want the learning process stop when the error reach 0.02, how do i do that? Thank you for the help.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(dimData,)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation = 'softmax'))
#configure the network
model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#train the network
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels_one_hot, batch_size=256, epochs = 20, verbose =1,
                    validation_data=(test_data, test_labels_one_hot))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should say early stopping this operation, this code you refer to.

```
from keras.callbacksimport EarlyStopping 

keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
   monitor='val_loss', 
   patience=0, 
   verbose=0, 
   mode='auto'
)

model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

you need to adjust val_acc equal to 0.98 when the stop.

Comment: okay, succeeded on implementing the callback. But i'm still not sure how to adjust the val_acc. How do i do that?